# How to install wine with dependency problems on OpenSUSE?

Tags: linux, opensuse, wine, dependencies

I am trying to install wine on OpenSUSE but I have a dependency problems.

It says that I need libgphoto2.so.2 and maybe I will need other packages later.

Do you know a way to solve this problem?

With Debian you can use maybe apt-offline or apt-zip but in OpenSUSE?

Comment: Why would you use `apt-offline`? Are you installing `wine` through `yum`?

Comment: no, I m not using yum but  I will use it if needed...

Comment: I just need to download all the packages needed by wine... I m currently using zypper and trying to install the wine.blabla.rpm

Comment: What version of OpenSuse are you using?  "zypper in wine" should be all that you need.  You can also use "yast sw_single" search for wine and tag it and the dependencies will be auto selected.

Answer (score 0):

To install [Wine on OpenSUSE](https://en.opensuse.org/Wine), you can try:

```
zypper in wine
```

Or following these methods:

#### Install Wine 1.7 on OpenSUSE 13.1:

```
$ sudo zypper ar -f http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine/openSUSE_13.1/ wine
$ sudo zypper refresh
$ sudo zypper install wine1.7 winetricks
```

#### Install Wine 1.7.20 on OpenSUSE 12.3

```
$ sudo zypper ar -f http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine/openSUSE_12.3/ wine
$ sudo zypper refresh
$ sudo zypper install wine
```

Source: [How To Install Wine 1.7.20 On OpenSUSE 13.1 And OpenSUSE 12.3](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-wine-1-7-20-on-opensuse-13-1-and-opensuse-12-3/)